# Displaying new webpage after HTML5 video is done

Tags: html, video, autoplay

I have a page which autoplays a video. How would I redirect and/or display a webpage when the video is done being watched? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `ended` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#event-media-ended):

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector('video'); // or whatever
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function (){
    window.location = 'http://newpage.com';
});
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/bCBhD/

Answer (score 0):

"onended" is a standard event for html objects which you can use. Documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp